# how to select everything before a string with regular expression?

Tags: regex

I have a string like:

`/09/2012 08:29:13  - @15a63b 20.708,243 ms [20.708,243] 1 PreparedStatement: exec patient`

I want to delete everything before the string `PreparedStatement`.  I'm using EditPlus editor. I need a regular expression to do it.

Does any body know how to combine this regular expression?

```
^.*?(?=PreparedStatement)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Perl, this will do:

```
$string =~ s/(.*?)(PreparedStatement: exec patient)/$2/;
```

Comment: Oh ho, that is a text editor! Then, if it closely matches Notepad++, here's what you should do: click the `replace` button, in the `replace` field, type `(.*?)(PreparedStatement: exec patient)`, and in the `replace by` field, type `\2`, and press `Enter`. In all probability, your editor won't understand `$2`, hence the more popular `\2`. See if it works.

Comment: Then perhaps Editplus has got a different syntax. Sorry, I can't help you out there.

Answer (score 0):

After long searching the Google and some website about regular expression i found this pattern: `.*PreparedStatement:`